# When V the vector space is a 2x2 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Consider the vector space $V = M_{2×2}(\mathbb{R})$ of real $2 × 2$ matrices.
>
> **a)** Write down an ordered basis $B$ for $V$.
>
> **b)** Suppose $Q = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$ is given and define a linear transformation $T : V → V$ by $T(X) = QX$ for each $X ∈ V$. Find the matrix $[T]_B$ of $T$ relative to the basis $B$.
>
> **c)** Is the matrix $[T]_B$ invertible? Why?

---

**My thoughts:**

**a)** An obvious basis for $V$ is $\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\}$

**b)** This is where I'm stuck. I suppose if I find a change of basis matrix from the traditional $F^4$ space to this $V$, I can find the inverse of that and apply it to $T$ to find $[T]_B$.

Since the vector space $V$ is not the traditional vector space. I'm not sure how to define this change of basis matrix.

Comment: The matrix of $T$ just have in the columns the $T$-images if your basis vectors (expressed in your basis).

Comment: Hint: let $[X]_B = (X_{11}, X_{12}, X_{21}, X_{22})$ denote the coordinate vector. Then, $[T]_B$ satisfies $[T(X)]_B = [T]_B [X]_B$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to worry about a change of basis matrix. To find $[T]_B$ you just need to apply $T$ to your basis vectors and write the results with respect to the basis $B$. For example:

$$
T \left ( \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \right) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 3 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Then, notice that

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 3 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = 1 \cdot\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + 0 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} +3 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + 0 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

and so the first column of the matrix $[T]_B$ is $(1,0,3,0)^T$. Just repeat this process on the other basis vectors to find the remaining columns of ${T}_B$.